# Can't run "/usr/bin/sudo myscript.sh" from Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: shell, informatica-powercenter

I have a command task and I want to run a script like '/usr/bin/sudo myscript.sh'
but it failed. But if you run "myscript.sh" it works fine.
Could you please give me any suggestion what can be wrong?

infadmin is in sudoers editor.

Comment: "nfadmin is in sudoers editor" - that's pretty meaningless unless you tell us how it is sudoers file. An error message would be good too.

Comment: Was about to comment with the same information as symcbean; also I would make sure that the user the Command task is running under is indeed infadmin (by trying to run `id` there)

Answer (score 0):

Informatica is funny with the slashes in command tasks, I'd suggest that if the same command works for you when ran manually then try using the other slashes i.e. \ instead of /.

Comment: Hello, Daniel, I tried your solution but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in sudoers file. After I make the same as on Production, everything works perfect.